# How to change the color of a button while it is pressed

Tags: dynamic, button

I want to change the color of a button while it is pressed, pause for a short time and then change the color back to the original color.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this (tried various forms of `DynamicModule` and `Dynamic`, but no luck). This is what I tried so far:

```
Manipulate[
  DynamicModule[{simulationFlag, bgnd = Automatic},
    simulationFlag = newSimulation;
    Pause[0.5];
    Dynamic[bgnd = Automatic; {simulationFlag}]],
  {{newSimulation, 0.02}, ControlType -> None},
  Row[{
    Button["New Simulation", Dynamic[newSimulation = newSimulation+1; {bgnd=Yellow}],
      Background -> Dynamic[bgnd]]}]
]
```

Comment: Could you please post whatever code you have tried so far? Also, do you want the button to revert after a short time while it is still pressed?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation: [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html) > Options > Background.

Comment: If you rework the example in the docs and add a `Pause` you will get what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason, @István's answer doesn't work here, so I rolled my own:

```
DynamicModule[{c = Yellow}, 
              Dynamic@Button["Press", Print["Pressed"]; 
                             c = Red; 
                             RunScheduledTask[c = Yellow; 
                                     RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {0}, AbsoluteTime[] + 3], 
                             Background -> c]]
```

Comment: I've corrected an error in my code (see comment below my post); could you please check whether it works on your end now? BTW, the problem with your approach is that multiple clicks start multiple tasks which stack up (check with `Dynamic@Refresh[ScheduledTasks[], UpdateInterval->.1]`). That's why I had to remove all tasks beforehand (not an elegant solution).

Comment: @IstvánZachar Your code still fails here. BTW, I see no problem with the tasks stacking up, as they are all removed after the delay from the last click has expired.

Comment: Ok, I see now, we've implemented different things here. Your code reverts back _n_ sec after the button is **released**, while mine reverts _n_ sec after the button is **pushed** but not released.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Ha! I was testing your code with my understanding :) The failure was the test case

Comment: Thank you Belisarius. This one is closer to what I had in mind. Before today I was completely oblivious to the RunScheduledTask and RemoveScheduledTask functions. Can you educate me on two items: 1. What is $ScheduledTask. 2. I can't match the form you have given with two times in the documentation. Can you expound on this. Thank you

Comment: @JackLaVigne Just type `$ScheduledTask` on your notebook and press `F1` ... and get used to do that. Everybody does it all the time while working in Mathematica

Answer (score 5):

Explanation in detail what this code does:

- Since the `Button[..., Background -> color]` has a rather ugly look, I use a `Panel` with colored background as the label of the button, this causes the button-in-a-button look.
- When simply clicked (**pressed and released immediately**), nothing special happes, the button (and `Panel`) only changes appearance for the short time the button is pressed, then reverts back to normal.
- However, when the button is **pressed but not released**, the behaviour is different: with the first registered event of `"MouseDown"`, a timed `task` is started that evaluates `delay` seconds later and reverts the color of the `Panel` back to normal *no matter whether the button is released or not*, but still leaves the `Button` look pressed.
- Releasing the button immediately removes any existing timed tasks.

So this code is a proof of principle that events *can happen* even while a button is in the iteraction phase. This might not be exactly what OP asked for but is my interpretation of the question.

```
delay = 2; (* time to stay blue when pressed *)
col = None; (* default color *)
down = False; (* default button state *)
EventHandler[Button[Dynamic@Panel[
     If[down, "Pushed", "Push!"], Background -> col, ImageMargins -> 5], 
     Appearance -> Dynamic@If[down, "Pressed", "Normal"]],
 {
  "MouseDown" :> (
    down = True;
    RemoveScheduledTask /@ ScheduledTasks[]; (* to prevent multiple click-overlaps *)
    col = Hue[.6, 1, 1, .2]; 
    task = RunScheduledTask[col = None; RemoveScheduledTask@task, {delay}]),
  "MouseUp" :> (down = False; Quiet@RemoveScheduledTask@task; col = None)
  }, PassEventsDown -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Strange ... doesn't work here (Mma 9 on winxp). It behaves as a normal button

Comment: I don't know how to get a carriage return so the comment I make is going to run all together. Your solution works fine but is above my level. Here is what I tried but it doesn't work.       Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{simulationFlag, bgnd = Automatic},
  simulationFlag = newSimulation;
  Pause[0.5];
  Dynamic[
   bgnd = Automatic;
   {simulationFlag}
   ]
  ]
 ,
 {{newSimulation, 0.02}, ControlType -> None},
 Row[{
   Button[
    "New Simulation",
    Dynamic[newSimulation = newSimulation + 1; {bgnd = Yellow}],
    Background -> Dynamic[bgnd]
    ]
   }]
 ]

Comment: @István I cannot understand why, when the scheduled task is executed, the button also gets raised (no more pressed). I do not find anything doing that in your code. Is it possible to keep it pressed? (MMA v9)

Comment: @user8074 Thanks for pointing it out! Actually, if you check the previous version, you can see that I made a mistake and accidentally merged `Button` option `Appearance` into the `Panel`. Strangely enough, it worked, so I missed it. This new version should behave as expected.

Comment: @István now what I see is quite unusual: two buttons one over the other. When I click them, both get pressed. Then, after 2 second, the inner button lifts up, while the outer button remains pressed. After releasing, both buttons get up. It may be that the color change event cancels the button-pressed event for some reason. Do you see the same?

Comment: @user8074 But that is **exactly** what I wanted to achieve :) The "inner" button is the `Panel` with the colored/white bg, because I do not like the look of `Button[..., Background->color]` - on Windows it is pretty ugly.

Comment: In Ver. 12.1.0.0 the code above, when executed, generates the error "RemovedScehduledTask"The task ScheduledTaskObject[Unique ID:23 Repetitions 1] can not be found. after the delay once the button is pushed.

Comment: @StuartPoss `RunScheduledTask` is phased out with v12.1, you have to switch to `TaskExecute` and friends. More importantly, it seems that the definition of `RunScheduledTask` (and e.g. `ScheduledTasks`) have changed under the hood as they behave differently, as you have pointed it out (I guess that `task` is not visible anymore in v12.1 to be deleted, hence the message). For example, `Dynamic@ScheduledTasks[]` is now freezing the frontend, while `Dynamic@Tasks[]` works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways.  One uses [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpdateInterval.html).  The second uses [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clock.html).  The `Clock` method continually uses some CPU to update the front end all the while the alternate color (`Yellow`) is displayed.  The first method makes only one update.  In this way it is more efficient.

In both cases, when the button is pressed, the background color is replaced by a dynamic object that updates itself and persists only while the alternate color is displayed.  The dynamic object is then destroyed after the interval has elasped and the color is replaced with the default color (`Red`, by my choice).

`UpdateInterval` method:

```
DynamicModule[{bgnd = Red, timer = Null, switch},
 Button["go",
  bgnd = Yellow;
  switch = 0;
  timer = Hold @ Refresh[If[switch < 1, switch++, timer = Null; bgnd = Red], 
     UpdateInterval -> 2, TrackedSymbols :> {}],
  Background -> Dynamic[ReleaseHold @ timer; bgnd]
  ]
 ]
```

`Clock` method:

```
DynamicModule[{bgnd = Red, clicktime = 0, duration = 2},
 Button["go",
   clicktime = Clock[Infinity]; 
   bgnd = Hold @ If[Clock[Infinity] < clicktime + duration, Green, bgnd = Red],
   Background -> Dynamic[ReleaseHold @ bgnd]
   ]
 ]
```

---

With respect to the code added in an edit, which seems possibly to be seeking a different sort of behavior  -- that is, not for a certain amount of time, but while the `Manipulate` updates -- here is a simplified version that works:

```
Manipulate[
 Pause[0.5];
 bgnd = Automatic;
 newSimulation,
 {{newSimulation, 0.02}, ControlType -> None},
 {{bgnd, Automatic}, ControlType -> None}, 
 Button["New Simulation", newSimulation = newSimulation + 1; 
  bgnd = Yellow, Background -> Dynamic[bgnd]]]
```