# Is it possible to change the color of a Control option when selected?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

For this `Control` inside `Manipulate` (using `Setter` or `RadioButton`):

```
Control[{{opt,"A"},{"A","B","C"},Setter}]
```

Is it possible to make the color of the selection change? So if "A" is selected the button is Blue, while "B" and "C" are black.

I read this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38173/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-button-while-it-is-pressed) about a `Button` changing colors when clicked and tried to do something similar for my situation but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I believe your code should be `Control[{{opt,"A"},{"A","B","C"}}]`. I don't think you can add the `Setter` part. `Control` doesn't take options as far as I know, but if you select the setter you can change its background color in the Option Inspector.

Comment: Use `Control[{{opt, "A"}, {"A", "B", "C"}, ControlType -> Setter}]` then in another cell evaluate `Dynamic[opt]` and observe this second cell as you click on the labels in the `Setter`

Answer (score 3):

The way I read the documentation one can only control the background color of a `Setter` or `SetterBar`. That is to say the foreground color is not available to the user.

If you are willing to use buttons, then I think you can accomplish your goal. I used Cyan and Gray rather than Blue and Black for visibility.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   {opt, colA, colB, colC},

   Row[{
     Button["A", opt = A; colA = Cyan; colB = Gray;
                   colC = Gray, Background -> colA],
     Button["B", opt = B; colA = Gray; colB = Cyan;
                    colC = Gray, Background -> colB],
     Button["C", opt = C; colA = Gray; colB = Gray;
                   colC = Cyan, Background -> colC]
     }]
   }],

 {{opt, A}, ControlType -> None},
 {{colA, Cyan}, ControlType -> None},
 {{colB, Gray}, ControlType -> None},
 {{colC, Gray}, ControlType -> None}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]